# Data appear at least once for every record

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose i have three tables: Movie, branch, rented, where branch tells different branches of a movie rental shop. Now I want to find all the movies that has been rented at least once in every branch. I can't really get how to check whether they are rented **at least once in every branch.**

These are the tables i made

```
Movie(mid, title, genre, year)
Branch(bid, bname, baddress)
Rented(mid, bid, copyid, outdate, returndate, cost)
```

Comment: Any code that you've tried?

Comment: Select m.mid from Movie m, Branch b, Rented r where m.mid=r.mid and b.bid=r.bid. I've connected them like this, but couldn't get a logic for at least once in every branch.

Comment: Did you read the link @Jonathan gave you?

Answer (score 1):

Count branches per movie and compare with the total number of branches. Select movies thus found.

```
select *
from movie
where mid in
(
  select mid
  from rented
  group by mid
  having count(distinct bid) = (select count(*) from branch)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to return all movies that have been rented in each branch, you can use an aggregate for that and compare that to the count of overall branches:

```
SELECT m.mid
FROM branch b
    JOIN rented r ON b.bid = r.bid
    JOIN movie m ON r.mid = m.mid
GROUP BY m.mid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.bid) = (SELECT COUNT(bid) FROM branch)
```

Comment: How does this query return movies that have been rented on every branch?

Comment: @Lamak -- updated the answer to return any movie that has been rented at all branches...

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, that's not my downvote. (Also, I think that the `JOIN` with the `movie` table is not necessary since you are just obtaining the id of the movie)

Comment: @Lamak -- no worries, and I agree -- might not need the `join` at all, unless there could be records in the rented table that no longer exist in the branch or movie tables.  Thanks for the clarification nonetheless!